# Activator link: Which the best way to design?

Tags: php, security

I'm using PHP and i know that exists many similar question on this site about this. But i don't found a good incisive explanation about points like:

- the conventions for activators link
- the common vulnerability on the activators link

For now, think that i have only the below options to design a good activator link:

1. Store a unique token inside users table and two parameters to validate account activation: user identifier and your respective token on database. Could be like this:

   `$user->token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));`

   `hostname/accountConfirm?user=username&token=userUniqueToken`
2. Using only one parameters as token that have a  hashed secret value + user email string. This option would not require any database column to store the token. Something like this:

   `$secret = 'some_secret_string';`

   `$hashedToken = password_hash( $secret . $user->email, PASSWORD_DEFAULT );`

   `hostname/accountConfirm?token=($hashedToken)`

My questions:

- Which the the pros and cons of these?
- If has, what other good solutions?

Comment: I would go for Method 1, the token is completely irrelevant to the user's private information. Hackers cannot decipher the Unique token based on other information. They are forced to use a brute-force attack. If your unique string is long enough, it would take quite a long time to break. Also probably rewrite the activation url with htaccess

Answer (score 1):

It's riskier to access the database than not access the database, esp with unauthenticated users. You can avoid accessing the database in this step by using a hash-based message authentication code (HMAC). This also slows script-kiddies from trying to fill up your db.

So, I like your second option, but you still need to keep the email address / username around somewhere.

This is what I have used (pseudocode):

```
$email = 'user@example.com';
$expires = current time + 24 hours;
$userIP = getUserIP();

$hmac = hmac_function( $serverSecret, $email + $expires + $userIP );

//correctly escaping query params of course...

$confirmationURL = https://hostname/accountConfirm?email=$email&expires=$expires&ip=$userIP&hmac=$hmac
```

send URL to $email

in accountConfirm handler:

```
$email = $_GET['email'];
$expires = $_GET['expires'];
$userIP = $_GET['ip'];
$hmac = $_GET['hmac'];

$expectedHmac = hmac_function( $serverSecret, $email + $expires + $userIP);

if($expectedHmac != $hmac) {
  log 'evil request';
  throw 400 error;
}

//check user ip
//check expiry time
//proceed with registration
```

If someone messes with the IP, email addy, or expiry time, the HMAC will not match.

Comment: can explain to me why i would need to use de user ip?

Comment: you don't need to. it would let you check that the registration request came from the same ip as the confirmation click

Comment: yeah, i understand this part but this does not would limit the user to use the same device in these differents actions or am I confused??

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.